# Round down 44355/10 to -1 using c#

Tags: c#

How do I use round-down to -1 in C#.net like we use in excel?

In excel I do this:

```
ROUND-DOWN(44355/10,-1);
```

Output: 4430

I tried : `Math.Round(44355/10,-1)`

But this is giving me and error of:

> round must be between 0-15

Comment: when you do this: `44355/10` in C# it will perform an integer division. That means that the result will be an integer and the `.5` will be cut away simply

Comment: Here is a nice trick how you can exploit the integer division to obtain the desired result: `Console.WriteLine(44355/100*10);`

Comment: @MongZhu The nice trick might not give the expected result if one or both numbers are negative.

Comment: @Phil1970 that is probably possible. If OP would include more examples of input and expected output patterns I probably would have posted something different

Answer (score 2):

Basically Math.Round does not permit that, you could use your own implementation however, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044516/9515389)

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly want similar functionality to the Excel ROUND-DOWN function, try something like this...

```
public static float RoundDown(float value, int numDigits)
{
    if (numDigits > 0)
        return (float)Math.Round(value, numDigits);

    var iValue = (int)value;

    for (int i = numDigits, x = 10; i < 0; i++, x *= 10)
        iValue -= iValue % x;

    return iValue;
}
```

This produces the following results:

```
RoundDown(5.82f, 0);      // 5
RoundDown(-5.82f, 0);     // 5
RoundDown(5.82f, 1);      // 5.8
RoundDown(-5.82f, 1);     // -5.8
RoundDown(123.456f, -1);  // 120
RoundDown(-123.456f, -1); // -120
RoundDown(123.456f, -2);  // 100
RoundDown(-123.456f, -2); // -100
RoundDown(999.999f, -3);  // 0
RoundDown(-999.999f, -3); // 0
```